# Webpack 2 background image relative path not working

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less, webpack-2

When I specify an image in my react component using a relative path it loads just fine

component:

```
import myImg from '../img/myImg.jpg';
...
<img className="myImg" src={myImg} alt="amazing image" />
```

This works just fine. And when inspecting it gives the path as `http://localhost:8080/src/img/myImg.jpg`

However if I try to use the image as a background image the path is incorrect and I get a 404

CSS:

```
#mainContainer {
    background-image: url('../img/myImg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

This results in the path being `http://localhost:8080/css/src/img/myImg.jpg` which is incorrect. If I use a absolute url it works `background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/src/img/challenge.jpg');`

Webpack config:

```
...
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/less')
            ],
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { importLoaders: 1 }
                    },
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img')
            ],
            use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
    new ExtractTextPlugin('css/' + pkg.name + '.' + pkg.version + '.css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, 'src/template.js')})//,
]
...
```

What can be done to use a relative path in the css?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need anoter '../' in your relative path for your css.

```
#mainContainer {
    background-image: url('../../img/challenge.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the issue, but when I change it I get: module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../img/myImg.jpg' in '/Users/chaselester/code/git/blife/src/less'

Comment: It's a little confusing where the 'src' is coming from in the 'localhost:8080/css/src/im.....', as it's nowhere in your style. Maybe try ../src/img/challange.jpg?

Comment: No go. I am a bit confused at the path it is trying to resolve from when I do a background image: ...css/src/img... but when using an <img> tag the path resolved from is .../src/img/... No js added before like css is added before

Comment: Looks like it has to do with this `test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img')
            ],
            use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'` in your config.